# 80's/90's classic cartoon about kids kidnapped and turned into mute slinky skinny lizard-like humanoids

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Classic cartoon about kids kidnapped and turned into mute slinky skinny lizard like humanoids. They had faces kinda like the Momo faces.

This was like 80's 90's, made into a TV special. I think the boys ran away or were kidnapped in a carnival but were later turned into this slinky creepy-looking humanoid lizards who couldn't talk, so no one would know they were actual kids. They kind of wobbled funnily when they walked.

Their face looked like this:

[image: blakc and white picture of a bird-looking clown with big eyes]

Comment: Reminds me of a similar scene in _Pinnochio_ where boys who ran away to the Land of Toys were transformed into donkeys.

Comment: exactly , its something like that but the boys were turned into these slinky skinny looking lizards but they couldn't talk its pretty scary , i saw an emote last night that reminded me of it wish i can post it here to see if it refreshes anyones memory i was looking all over google but google has become less of  a search engine and more of a suggestive click bait thing , but i hope someone finds out what cartoon it is ,

Comment: https://static.cambridge.org/binary/version/id/urn:cambridge.org:id:binary:20170704080742322-0274:9781108182324:19833fig13_20.png?pub-status=live they had this face , they couldnt talk and they kinda wobbled funny when they walked , hope that helps a lil they were i think green also newt lizard like

Comment: Was this actually live-action, and not a cartoon?  The image you link to is live-action.

Comment: the link was just a sample of what the salamender skinny humanoids looked like , the link i posted was from an actual live action claymation thing but i used it as an example because i dont see an option where i can post the emote i saw that reminded me of that old cartoon , im still looking for it and i cant find it , all i remember is they had that face and they moved funny slinky but the spell wouldnt let them talk so no one would know they were actual kids

Comment: OMG !! i found it , it was The Care Bears in the Land Without Feeling i linked the spot of the video so ya can see the lizard looking children https://youtu.be/49ekb7xW8gU?t=1074

Comment: @LoganX: When you return, you can accept an answer (including your own if you wish) by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: How is that tied to the picture in the question?

Answer (score 1):

OP found their answer in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222561/classic-cartoon-about-kids-kidnapped-and-turned-into-mute-slinky-skinny-lizard-l#comment608548_222561); it was *The Care Bears in the Land Without Feelings*, a television special of the titular Care Bears released in 1983.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Care_Bears_in_the_Land_Without_Feelings):

> Kevin, a boy on Earth, is upset because he has to move away from his younger friend Donna. Declaring that he doesn't care, he decides to run away and ends up in The Land Without Feelings, which is ruled by a misanthropic and winter-centric mad scientist named Professor Coldheart. **He turns Kevin into a green amphibian-like goblin via a soda-like potion and declares him a slave. The Care Bears, along with Donna, go into the Land Without Feelings to save Kevin along with the other children who were turned into Coldheart's goblin slaves.** Tenderheart Bear makes an attempt to climb up to Coldheart's castle, but is caught in a trap by Coldheart himself on the way up. Wish Bear makes an immediately granted wish to be teleported to Coldheart's castle with Grumpy Bear and Donna (and all the other Care Bears too, including Tenderheart), after several times being interrupted when attempting to make a wish and seeing if it would actually come true. The Care Bears use their magic 'Care Bear Stare' to change Kevin and the other children back to human, and Coldheart makes a break for it.

The episode is available on YouTube, here timestamped to the boy's transformation into the lizard: